# Cython: Access to private C members of CPython object

Tags: python, c, types, cython

In http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#external-extension-types it's explained how to access internal (hidden or "private") C-level members of objects in a Python extension module.

I want to access the internal member `db` from a `sqlite3.Connection` object which is defined in a struct `pysqlite_Connection` in file `Modules/_sqlite/connection.h` of the Python2 source. I do it like this:

File connection.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "connection.h":
    struct sqlite3Connection:
        sqlite3 *db

    ctypedef class __builtin__.xConnection [object pysqlite_Connection]:
        cdef sqlite3Connection conn
```

and then use it like this:

File vtables.pxd:

```
from connection cimport xConnection

cdef dbname(xConnection c):
    cdef sqlite3 *d
    return sqlite3_db_filename(c.conn.db, "main")
```

This compiles with cython, *but* when I run the C compiler on the result, I get:

```
vtables.c:635:69: error: ‘pysqlite_Connection’ has no member named ‘conn’
   __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBytes_FromString(sqlite3_db_filename(__pyx_v_c->conn.db, __pyx_k_main)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 6; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                     ^
```

The generated C code seems to act as if I was accessing the `pysqlite_Connection` struct instead of the wrapping `xConnection`, complaining about access to a member `conn` which is of course not in `pysqlite_Connection` but in my `xConnection` Cython class. But in the `dbname` function the parameter is clearly defined as `xConnection`. This seems like a bug in the `cython` compiler. Or did I miss something?

I tried to give the `type` parameter as in the documentation, like:

```
ctypedef class __builtin__.xConnection [object pysqlite_Connection, type pysqlite_ConnectionType]:
    cdef sqlite3Connection conn
```

but then `cython` crashed.

If this method is obsolete/not supported anymore, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've quite done what you think you've done. You haven't created a wrapper class called `xConnection`. You've assured Cython that there is already a class called `__builtin__.xConnection` and that it is stored using the C structure `pysqlite_Connection`, and it contains a `sqlite3Connection` struct which contains a member called `db`.

I think what you want to tell Cython that there is already a class called `sqlite.Connection`, that is stored in the C structure `pysqlite_Connection` and which contains a member called `db`:

```
cdef extern from "connection.h":
    # I assume you definite this somewhere else
    ctypedef struct sqlite3:
        pass

    ctypedef class sqlite.Connection [object pysqlite_Connection]:
        cdef sqlite3* db

cdef dbname(Connection c):
    return sqlite3_db_filename(c.db, "main")
```

Comment: Seems to work. Except calling `sqlite3_db_filename` crashes in the preparation of the call. I probably have to open a new question for that.

Comment: Works now. The return type of `sqlite_db_filename` has to be defined properly.