# Importing `CPython/Objects/genobject.c` into Cython

Tags: python, cython, cpython

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086984/cython-access-to-private-c-members-of-cpython-object) and this [reference](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#external-extension-types), there are examples of importing c-header files into Cython, but there is no answer to how can one import a `.c` file content into Cython.

The `.c` file which I am interested to import into Cython for my use is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/genobject.c

I have two questions:

**One**

How do I import a `.c` file into Cython?

**Two**

Do I need to have the `.c` file within my directory for it to be accessed? If yes, how do I go about getting `https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/genobject.c` so that I can use its content in Cython?

I have two `.pxd` files, `cpy.pxd` and `src.pxd`.

In `cpy.pxd`, I have:

```
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    cdef int gen_is_coroutine(object o)
```

In `src.pxd`, I use it as usual:

```
if gen_is_coroutine(__value):
    do_something(__value)
```

I get this Cython compiler error:

```
constmeta.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol gen_is_coroutine
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\cy_src\constmeta.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
```

Comment: I guess gen_is_corroutin is not marked as public, and thus not visible to the linker (it is definied in python.dll). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216452/5769463, but there are better sources around.

Comment: You can add C code directly in Cython files, which probably means that `#include` directives with a C source will also work: https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#verbatim-c